# DFA that accepts all the strings with exactly two a’s and more than two b’s

Tags: theory

[image]It works I checked it but I don't know how to make it smaller :(
the question is in my book,I can solve but it took too much time and effort and I'm pretty sure there's a simple soloution.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site :)
It would be helpful if you posted your solution so we can give some feedback on that. I think there is a DFA with 6 states recognizing the described language.

Comment: @Watercrystal thank you :)
this is embarassing but,I put a pic in the post but it keeps swallowing it idk what to do xD
Edit:Ok I fixed it finally,I dragged and dropped.

Comment: @Watercrystal I should also mention I'm new to theory,you say 6 states?it took me 16! you must be really experienced with theory,I started it just a couple of days ago.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization

Comment: @D.W. I heard about the minimization but I'm really new and don't know how to do it yet,I still can barely construct DFAs but thank you I'll try to make it work

Comment: @SaifShalan associate each state to a distinct pair $(i,j)$ where $i \in \{0, 1, 2\}$ represents the number of as seen so far and $j \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ represents the number of $b$s seen so far. Here $j=3$ actually means "3 ore more".

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake reading the question, 6 states do not suffice. But the answer given works.

Answer (score 0):

My solution might not be *the smallest*, however it's more organized (and still smaller than your solution):

[image: DFA]

The column number represents the number of "A"s seen, and the row number is the number of "B"s seen. This DFA solves the language $\{w\ |\ \#_a(w)=2,\ \#_b(w)\ge 2\}$

If you intended to solve the language $\{w\ |\ \#_a(w)=2,\ \#_b(w)> 2\}$, then just add another row of states (similarly to the rows here).

Hope this helps! (even though, as I stated, it might and probably is not the *minimal* solution)

Comment: Should be minimal, however I think the answer would be more clear if you specifically showed the DFA for the language specified by the OP rather than a variant of it. As for proving minimality, if I am not mistaken again, it seems like a straightforward proof using [the Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem).

Comment: Transition from s9 on "B" is missing.

Comment: Oh you're right. Its a terminating state so the "B" transition should be to itself

Comment: The condition was “more than 2 b’s”, not “2 or more b’s”. You need another row.